# How to make JavaScript function runs only when parameter changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and every time something changes it renders the whole component. Although I have a smallest possible component, but it runs a heavy function. I don't want this function to run on every render if its parameters has not changed. Something like `React.memo` (basically don't re-render a component if its props have not changed). Is there an equivalent of `React.memo` for static JavaScript functions?

**NOTE:** I don't want to pull in a library such as `reselect`. There has to be a better way!

---

**Edit:** I feel like I was not very clear about what I was looking for. Let me ask this with an example,

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-2xe2m?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Every time I click on `+` or `-`, it runs the `pleaseMemoizeThisFunction` function, even though its parameter has not changed. How can I have this function only runs when any of its parameters change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the useMemo hook around your functions and it will not run unless the params have changed.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

const computed = useMemo(() => calculateExpensive(param1, param2), [param1, param2]);

Comment: I updated my question. I am not really sure how to use `React.useMemo`. Maybe that is what I am looking for. How do you have `param1` and `param2` defined?

Comment: any chance that you can show me with my `sandbox` example above?

Comment: I think it would be best if you updated react to the latest version.
memo and useMemo is not available in the version in your sandbox.
Here is an example with latest version
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-platform-105cy

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple memoization implementation that checks wether the function is called with the same arguments as the last time, and only recalculates the result if they differ.

Seing in your sandbox that you use Typescript, I've added the Types to this function.

```
function memo<A extends any[], R>(fn:(...args:A) => R) {
  let value:R, 
    before: A = {length:NaN} as any;

  const sameAsBefore = (v:A[number], i:number) => v === before[i];
  function memoized (...args:A):R {
    if (args.length !== before.length || !args.every(sameAsBefore)) {
        before = args;
        value = fn.apply(this, args);
    }
    return value;
  }


}
```

usage:

```
const pleaseMemoizeThisFunction = memo((a: string, b: string): string => {
  console.count("function run: ");
  // it will do some heavy stuff here
  return `I am done with ${a} and ${b}`;
});
```

or like `this.someMethod = memo(this.someMethod);`

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution here, but it does not seem to work for me. Any chance that you can have a look? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-pb7kv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&expanddevtools=1

Comment: I don't really understand your `memo` function. But I am ok with it, as long as it works and I can use it in my project.